# Остановка autoplay в swiper слайдер при наведении

Tags: javascript

Хочу использовать swiper слайдер. Я уже разобрался как сделать автоматическое перелистывание картинок.

Что нужно дописать в скрипт, чтобы при наведении на слайдер мышкой он останавливался, а, если убрать курсор со слайдера, снова запускалось перелистывание автоматически?

Вот код:

```
 var swiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
  spaceBetween: 30,
  effect: 'fade',
  loop: true,
  autoplay: {
    delay: 3000,
    disableOnInteraction: false,        
  },
  pagination: {
    el: '.swiper-pagination',
    clickable: true,
  },
  navigation: {
    nextEl: '.swiper-button-next',
    prevEl: '.swiper-button-prev',
  },        
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Здесь](https://swiperjs.com/api/) подробное API слайдера.
Слушатели `mouseenter/mouseleve` работают в рамках текущего инициализированного слайдера.
Если у вас в проекте будет 2 и более таких слайдера, всего лишь нужно добавить дополнительный класс-селектор для элемента к которому применяете свойства.

К примеру:

```
const swiper2 = new Swiper('.swiper-container.swiper-2', {
  // Свойства и методы слайдера
});
```

```js
const swiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
  spaceBetween: 30,
  effect: 'fade',
  loop: true,
  autoplay: {
    delay: 500,
    disableOnInteraction: false,
  },
  pagination: {
    el: '.swiper-pagination',
    clickable: true,
  },
  navigation: {
    nextEl: '.swiper-button-next',
    prevEl: '.swiper-button-prev',
  },
  on: {
    init() {
      this.el.addEventListener('mouseenter', () => {
        this.autoplay.stop();
      });

      this.el.addEventListener('mouseleave', () => {
        this.autoplay.start();
      });
    }
  },
});
```

```css
.swiper-container {
  width: 500px;
  height: 300px;
}

.swiper-slide {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 18px;
  background: #fff;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Swiper/4.5.1/css/swiper.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Swiper/4.5.1/js/swiper.min.js"></script>

<div class="swiper-container">
  <div class="swiper-wrapper">
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 1</div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 2</div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 3</div>
  </div>
  <div class="swiper-pagination"></div>
  <div class="swiper-button-prev"></div>
  <div class="swiper-button-next"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Благодарю, очень помогли:-)

Answer (score 2):

Добавьте события mouseover и mouseout

```
document.getElementsByClassName("swiper-container")[0].addEventListener("mouseover", function( ) {
    swiper.autoplay.stop();
});

document.getElementsByClassName("swiper-container")[0].addEventListener("mouseout", function( ) {
    swiper.autoplay.start();
});
```

Или jQuery

```
$(".swiper-container").mouseenter(function() {
    swiper.autoplay.stop();
});

$(".swiper-container").mouseleave(function() {
    swiper.autoplay.start();
});
```